# Usando regex de python, cómo puedo obtener el mismo string en diferentes cadenas

Tags: python, regex

Tengo 2 strings:

- `99.95 was(138)`
- `160.56`

Necesito crear un regex que me permita **obtener** estos números:

- `138`
- `160.56`

en el primer caso, necesito lo que está dentro de los paréntesis, y en el segundo necesito seleccionar todo el número, usando el mismo regex. Gracias.

Tengo este: `[(]?\d+[)]?$`, pero en el primer caso me está seleccionando también los paréntesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según interpreté de tu pregunta:

1. Si hay un número entre paréntesis, obtener ese número.
2. De lo contrario, obtener el primer número en el texto

#### Regex

```
(?:^.*?\()?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

#### Descripción

- Primero intenta consumir todos los caracteres desde el principio del texto hasta el primer paréntesis `^.*?\(`

  - Esto dentro de un grupo (*non-capturing group*) para hacerlo opcional `(?:^.*?\()?` y que funcione en los 2 casos
- Luego busca un número que puede tener decimales `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

  - Y esto dentro de un grupo (*capturing group*) entre paréntesis `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`, para almacenarlo y poder referenciarlo con `.group(1)`

#### Código

```python
import re

p = re.compile(r'(?:^.*?\()?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')

str1 = '99.95 was(138.5)'
str2 = '160.56'

res1 = p.search(str1)
print(res1.group(1))

res2 = p.search(str2)
print(res2.group(1))
```

#### Resultado

```
138.5
160.56
```

Comment: Perfecto! Funciona, mira este que también funciona que pude hacer `(\d+.\d+)(?!.*\d)`.

Comment: @ElvisSaavedra tu ejemplo no funcionaría. Probalo contra `4A8` o contra `(124)__ 666` y vas a ver que está mal. Si te interesa aprender acerca de expresiones regulares, hay muchos tutoriales en la web. Fijate en http://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info que hay algunos listados, y si hay algo que no entiendas, más que bienvenido a hacer otra preguntas... Me alegro que te haya ayudado

Comment: Hola, tienes razón, no funciona para los ejemplos que pusiste, pero para lo que yo necesitaba si funcionaba bien. De todas maneras gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

Siempre va a coger los paréntesis por que son parte de su sintaxis, se usan para generar grupos, pero nada que no se pueda procesar con python.

La forma más sencilla de hacer esto es usando un `or` en regex `|`:

```
(\((\d{3})\))|[\d]{3}\.[\d]{2}
```

La expresion va a campturar el contenido del paréntesis (incluido los paréntesis) o un bloque de números de 3 dígitos y 2 decimales. Va a funcionar siempre y cuando tengas los mismos strings.

Probando con python en la consola:

```
>>> r = '(\((\d{3})\))|[\d]{3}\.[\d]{2}'
>>> t1 = '99.95 was(138)'
>>> t2 = '160.56'
>>> p = re.compile(r)
>>> p.search(t1).group().replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
'138'
>>> p.search(t2).group().replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
'160.56'
```

Puedes probar las expresiones [aquí](http://www.regexr.com/).

Tambien se puede lograr lo que buscas usando condicionales, y serviría para otras cadenas similares, pero si esas son tus dos únicas cadenas esto va a servir.

Comment: Buenas, gracias por tu respuesta, en base a tu ejemplo, si en la variable `t2` le pongo un número con decimal no lo selecciona. Los valores pueden tener decimales como no tenerlos...

Comment: El tema no es con decimales, sino que asume que siempre son 3 dígitos en la parte entera y 2 decimales, que se podía malinterpretar de la pregunta